# Trying yoga with multiple injuries

Tags: injury, yoga, rehabilitation, functional-strength

I've had an abundance of injuries from the gym over the last couple of years despite having spent an awful lot of money on physio sessions and personal trainers... a lot of these injuries were my own fault but a number of them were down to bad advice that I was given.

I am currently juggling an aggravated lower hamstring tendon in my left leg, tendonitis in my right tricep and impingement in my right shoulder. None of these injuries are severe but they're being very stubborn and struggling to go away despite my efforts.

I am thinking I am gonna have to give the gym a miss for a while, a decision that has taken a long time for me to make.

Whilst I plan to focus mostly on a more functional / rehabilitation routine I'd also like to take up some other physical activity to stop me going crazy. It would also be good if it was something that could help my joints in some way.

I've heard yoga is great for your joints, but would it be a good idea for someone in my position? Some of the poses look like they would put a lot of strain on your arms (and elbows in some cases) and also I don't think I should stretch my left hamstring too much because of my injury.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely check with a physician that knows and understands your injuries for an opinion. I personally used yoga for a rehab activity and quickly discovered which poses and transitions were painful or at least not beneficial.

If you have done Physiotherapy before, you likely know how to judge how your body feels. Some poses can aggravate injured joints and muscles, and others may be excellent at maintaining tone and flexibility. My region has drop in yoga for people with injuries. At least look for something like that, at your local hospital, where you can ask for feedback from someone that understands the nature of injuries.

There are all kinds of yoga programs. Sounds like something to maintain flexibility and fine muscle control would be beneficial. Of course without knowing you, it's just my general feedback to encourage you to keep looking for new ways to work out that will suit you better than what you've done in the past.

On a side note, for being prone to injuries or stuck with multiple injuries, have you looked at aquatic therapy? Physio in the pool, I mean.

Comment: Thankyou! I've actually been to 3 different physios over the last couple years... the last two have been pretty good but the first guy was useless and made a number of my injuries even worse with his advice. I've not looked into aquatic therapy as of yet, but could be one to add to the list!